# Implement protocol through methods declared in superclass?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I'm wondering if it is possible, in a certain subclass, to "recognise" methods declared in it's *superclass* as implementations of methods declared in a protocol the *subclass* adheres to, given that they have the same signatures.

It kind of gets hard to even formulate this, that's why any searches I made turned out fruitless so far.

But let me make the case with an example for better understanding.

Protocol:

```
@protocol TheProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)theProtocolMethod;

@end
```

Superclass:

```
// Superclass does not adhere to TheProtocol
@interface TheSuperClass : NSObject

- (void)theProtocolMethod;

@end

@implementation TheSuperClass

- (void)theProtocolMethod
{
    // stuff
}

@end
```

Subclass:

```
// SubClass adheres to TheProtocol but does not implement it's methods
// since they are implemented in the class it is subclassing. Is this OK?
@interface TheSubClass : TheSuperClass <TheProtocol>

@end

@implementation TheSubClass

@end
```

Is this anywhere close to being "OK"?
What about the case `TheSubClass` was in fact a category of `TheSuperClass` (declaring adherence to `TheProtocol`) and not a subclass?

**A bit more context:**

It's a scenario involving Core Data. I need to publish an accessor defined in an Entity Class, in a Protocol that will be used in a separate Framework for developing plugins for my app. The Protocol itself is fully implemented by a Category of the Core Data Entity Class, except for said accessor which is implemented in the Entity Class itself, hence my question.

Comment: Did you try it to see if it worked? If it doesn't work, it should complain that you haven't implemented a method from the protocol, but if it does work, then there should be no warnings.

Comment: I did eventually try the category alternative. Indeed no warnings appeared. Removing the method declaration from the base class lit up the warning about unimplemented method. So I guess it does the trick in he end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absolute terms, this is perfectly legal. Calling `-theProtocolMethod` on an instance of `TheSubClass` would indeed invoke `TheSuperClass` implementation if `TheSubClass` itself doesn't implement it. You could even call `[super theProtocolMethod]` in your subclass implementation, if you wanted.

If `TheSubClass` was a category on `TheSuperClass`, the superclass implementation would still be called. However, implementing `-theProtocolMethod` in the category would replace the super class implementation, so you have to be careful here.

Subjectively, in code-design terms, it's maybe a little odd. You essentially have two separate declarations of the same method to manage, which could potentially cause problems if you tried to refactor. I'm guessing the superclass in your case is a library class that you cannot change. Otherwise, I can't see why `TheSuperClass` shouldn't just conform to the protocol, rather than declare the method separately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the question I don't consider implementations of the method in subclass or category, so I guess replacing and maintaining multiple implementations would not be an issue. I've edited my question as well to provide more context (it's about Core Data).

Comment: The advantage to the duplicate declaration in the super class interface is you could tag it with NS_REQUIRES_SUPER which you can't do in the protocol. However, you could also add a TheSuperClassSubclass.h header that has a category @interface TheSuperClass(Protected) <TheProtocol> and then include that in subclass .m files, and in the TheSuperClass.m file add a class extension TheSuperClass()<TheProtocol> to help you make sure you got all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you're saying the superclass is already compliant with the protocol.

If the compiler complains, you can implement wrapper methods in your subclass that simply call super and return any return value from the call to super.